# How can I solve this limit?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How can I solve this limit?

[image]

thanks you!!!

Comment: How is it related to _Mathematica_ programming?

Comment: This is not a site for homework problems that show no coding attempt. There may be related sites for that, I'm not sure.

Comment: As the sum in the denominator is simply n^(5/2) the expression in question is just the Riemann sum the limit of which gives Integrate[x^(3/2),{x,0,1}] -> 2/5. The same idea was applied in my question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95126/limit-of-partial-sums-involving-inverse-squares

Answer (score 3):

You can easily look up manual, and employ

```
Limit[Sum[k*Sqrt[k], {k, 1, n}]/(Sqrt[n]*Sum[2*k - 1, {k, 1, n}]), 
   n -> Infinity]

(* 2/5 *)
```

Also track the dependence of the limit on parameter (u) using

```
ListPlot[Table[{u, 
   Limit[Sum[k*Sqrt[k], {k, 1, n}]/(Sqrt[n]*Sum[u*k - 1, {k, 1, n}]), 
    n -> Infinity]}, {u, 1, 4, 0.1}]]
```

[image]

The arrow indicates value corresponding to  u=2