# How to find a more precise value of integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics

Mathematica 11 produces

```
NIntegrate[ArcCot[x]*Sin[x]/(5/4 + Cos[x]), {x, 0, Infinity}, 
 Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory", AccuracyGoal -> 10, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 20]
0.746733605129940959
```

This is 4.573.3 from  Gradshteyn & Ryzhik. Up to G&R the result is

```
 N[Pi*Log[3/2/(1 + 1/2*Exp[-1])], 10]
   0.7433557514
```

The question arises: how to obtain it in Mathematica?

Comment: I guess G&R is Gradshteyn & Ryzhik

Comment: @Michael E2:Thank you for your interest to the question. You are right.

Comment: `, AccuracyGoal -> 80, WorkingPrecision -> 160` yields `0.74394...` Other than that, standard techniques don't do much.

Comment: @Feyre: Thank you for your interest to the question. I am troubled by no warning and error estimate.

Comment: Your can get closer approximation if you split range {0,Infinity} into say {0,300 Pi} and {300 Pi, Infinity}. For the second interval "ExtrapolatingOscillatory" and high working presicion is ok. The first range is more complicated and even using high working precision and increased MaxRecursion hardly helps to get correct 5-th digit.

Comment: @user18792 For the first interval you could use something like `Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 101}` -- such an integral should yield to a high enough order Gauss-Kronrod or Clenshaw-Curtis rule.

Comment: Does it help to split `ArcCot[x]` into the sum of `ArcCot[x] - 1/x` and `1/x` and compute the two integrals separately?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an extrapolatory approach based on Richardson extrapolation of the integrals over each "period." (`Richardson[]` code from [Anton Antonov's answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95166/4999)):

```
Clear[Richardson]
Richardson[A_, n_, N_] := 
 Total@Table[(A[n + k]*(n + k)^N*If[OddQ[k + N], -1, 1])/(k! (N - k)!), {k, 0, N}]

(* the integral from 2 n Pi to 2 (n+1) Pi *)
Clear[aa];
aa[n_Integer /; n >= 0] := 
  aa[n] = NIntegrate[ArcCot[x]*Sin[x]/(5/4 + Cos[x]), {x, 2 n Pi, 2 (n + 1) Pi}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 50];
```

We get around machine precision with 100 terms plus 6 extrapolation terms:

```
sf[n_] := Sum[aa[i], {i, 0, n}]; (* partial sum = integral over {0, 2 (n+1) Pi} *)
Richardson[sf, 100, 6]
% - Pi*Log[3/2/(1 + 1/2*Exp[-1])]
(*
  0.743355751361227474780881457479018423835    
  -2.97535713733265290609713*10^-16
*)
```

Without extrapolation:

```
sf[100]
% - Pi*Log[3/2/(1 + 1/2*Exp[-1])]
(*
  0.74207790286093203962531860751097243182349263171074
  -0.00127784850029573269127658323333660172377741318898
*)
```

---

*Update*

More extrapolatory terms yields an approximation accurate to machine precision with many fewer terms overall:

```
Richardson[sf, 1, 16]
% - Pi*Log[3/2/(1 + 1/2*Exp[-1])]
(*
  0.74335575136122767678505611095516483469029
  -9.553153907978914419885698*10^-17
*)
```

Comment: This is effectively a manual reimplementation of [Longman](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S030500410003187X)'s (`"ExtrapolatingOscillatory"`) method, with the only possible difference of Michael using Richardson extrapolation, and the internal routines using the Wynn $\varepsilon$ algorithm (via `SequenceLimit[]`).

Answer (score 6):

You didn't say how accurate you wanted it to be.

You can convert the expression to exponential form, which can be easier to `NIntegrate[]`.

```
expr = ArcCot[x]*Sin[x]/(5/4 + Cos[x]) // TrigToExp;

NIntegrate[expr, {x, 0, ∞}, 
 Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory", AccuracyGoal -> 80, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 160, MaxRecursion -> 100, MinRecursion -> 50]
```

This produces as answer `0.74363...` with the warnings you anticipated.
Further increasing values shows incrementally more accurate results.

Not really great.

So, let's design our intersections manually:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Total[Table[
   NIntegrate[expr, {x, i - Pi, i}, AccuracyGoal -> 10, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 20], {i, Pi, 10000 Pi, Pi}]]]
```

> `{57.0974, 0.7433299386508148184}`

Takes a while, but it's a lot more accurate, naturally the further you take it, the more accurate it becomes, but I don't have infinite computing time right now.

Comment: @ Feyre: Many thanks from me to you for your work. I think the accuracy obtained by you is sufficient in most cases. The purpose of the question is the following. The integrand is not very complicated and oscillating. Because of this a quite accurate answer done without tricks is expected, not with the relative error 0.005. I believe this can be reached so I forbear to accept your answer as yet. I voted up your answer.

Comment: @user64494 Don't worry, I understand you wanting a more formal answer, which has now come.

Answer (score 4):

Although the question was most probably meant to address accuracy problems in NIntegrate it might be of interest to see how to use Mathematica to calculate the exact symbolic result of the integral.

We shall derive the exact expression for the more general integral of Gradshteyn/Ryshik 4.573.3:

```
fi := Integrate[
  ArcCot[r x] Sin[p x]/(1 + 2 q Cos[p x] + q^2), {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

and then take the numerical value in the end.

fi reduces to the integral of the OP by letting

```
rep = {r -> 1, p -> 1, q -> 2};
fop = q^2 fi /. rep;
```

As Mathematica does not evaluate the integral we make a series expansion with respect to the parameter q around q = 0 and integrate term by term which gives us for the first few terms (for simplicity in list format)

```
(2 p)/\[Pi] Integrate[
    ArcCot[r x] List @@ 
      Normal[Series[Sin[p x]/(1 + 2 q Cos[p x] + q^2), {q, 0, 3}]], {x, 
     0, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> {q^2 < 1, p > 0, r > 0}] // 
  Expand // Simplify

(* Out[2]= {1 - E^(-(p/r)), 1/2 (-1 + E^(-((2 p)/r))) q, 1/3 (1 - E^(-((3 p)/r))) q^2, 1/4 (-1 + E^(-((4 p)/r))) q^3} *)
```

It is easy to guess the general scheme and see that the these terms are generated by the formula

```
-1/q Table[(-q)^k (1 - Exp[-k p/r])/k, {k, 1, 4}] // Expand // Simplify

(* Out[3]= {1 - E^(-(p/r)), 1/2 (-1 + E^(-((2 p)/r))) q, 1/3 (1 - E^(-((3 p)/r))) q^2, 
 1/4 (-1 + E^(-((4 p)/r))) q^3} *)
```

Extending the range of k of the sum to infinity and assuming q^2<1, thus taking care of convergence, we obtain

```
filt1 = -\[Pi]/(2 p q) Sum[(-q)^k (1 - Exp[-k p/r])/k, {k, 1, \[Infinity]}] //
   Simplify

(* Out[35]= (\[Pi] (Log[1 + q] - Log[1 + E^(-(p/r)) q]))/(2 p q) *)
```

This formula holds for q^2<1. 
For q^2 > 1 we write w=1/q in the definition of fi and arrive at the formula

```
figt1 = w^2 filt1 /. q -> w /. w -> 1/q

(* Out[36]= (\[Pi] (Log[1 + 1/q] - Log[1 + E^(-(p/r))/q]))/(2 p q) *)
```

Finally, inserting the values of the parameters we find for the integral of the OP

```
fop = q^2 figt1 /. rep

(* Out[38]= \[Pi] (Log[3/2] - Log[1 + 1/(2 E)]) *)
```

And its numerical value is

```
N[%, 20]

(* Out[39]= 0.74335575136122777232 *)
```

Comment: @ Dr. Wolfgang Hintze : Many thanks from me to you for your work well done.