# NIntegrate not giving the correct value

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions

I have an integrand which cannot be integrated analytically:

```
pr[x_] = -Pi/4 x^2 Cos[x^2] FresnelC[Sqrt[2] x/Sqrt[Pi]]^2;
```

but I also have an approximation to it:

```
g[x_] = Sqrt[\[Pi]/2]/(16 x) - Cos[x^2]/32 + (3 Cos[x^2])/(128 x^4) - 
   1/16 \[Pi] x^2 Cos[x^2] + (Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] Cos[2 x^2])/(16 x) + 
   1/32 Cos[3 x^2] - (7 Cos[3 x^2])/(128 x^4) - (3 Sin[x^2])/(
   128 x^6) + Sin[x^2]/(32 x^2) + (3 Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] Sin[2 x^2])/(
   32 x^3) - 1/8 Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] x Sin[2 x^2] - (3 Sin[3 x^2])/(
   128 x^6) + Sin[3 x^2]/(32 x^2);
```

I try to estimate the error between the integrand and its approximation by doing:

```
NIntegrate[pr[x] - g[x], {x, 10, ∞}, 
  Method -> "MonteCarlo",
  PrecisionGoal -> 10]
```

but it gives me a large value (-7e8) whereas I know that it should be very small.

How do I correct the numerical integration?

Comment: I dont get what you want to do. Is $g(x)$ and approximation to $pr(x)$? If yes, based on what approach? Why do you want to evaluate the error with an integral? Is this a question about the software Mathematica or is it a math question? Please clarify.

Comment: g(x) is an approximation to pr(x), yes, based on expanding the Fresnel function for large x. Visually, the two functions overlap for x > 1, so the difference between them must converge. I want to verify this by numerically integrating their difference between 10 and infinity.

Comment: This is not a Mathematica problem  since the integral of pr[x_] over the interval {x, 10, \[Infinity]} diverges.

Comment: user64494, I am not saying it doesn't. I am saying that the integral of the difference pr(x) - g(x) converges.

Comment: @Morgan: Why do you think so? Can you base that statement "I know that it should be very small"?

Comment: @user64494 Because g(x) is a Taylor expansion of pr(x) at infinity. Also, someone else has done the same calculation before, only with less terms in the expansion, and managed to integrate it with Mathematica to get a converging result. Unless they published an error in a scientific journal, it should still be valid.

Comment: @Morgan: Please, elaborate " Because g(x) is a Taylor expansion of pr(x) at infinity" to base the convergence (see http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FresnelC.html ). Also "someone else" does not sound seriously.

Comment: Sure, g[x_] is obtained with the following code:
-Pi/4 x^2 Cos[
     x^2] Series[
      FresnelC[Sqrt[2] x/Sqrt[Pi]], {x, \[Infinity], 5}]^2 // Normal //
   TrigReduce // Expand

Comment: @Morgan: The question was: why does the  the integral  converge? Sorry, you didn't answer it.

Comment: @Morgan Any feedback?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The integrand, as an exact function, seems a reasonably well-behaved oscillatory function that can be integrated (numerically) successfully via extrapolation; however, as a numerical function, it is horrible.  (Expect the code below to run ***slowly***, from seconds to minutes.)  To evaluate at `x -> 100.` accurately you need `4343` digits of accuracy, or you'll be way off:

```
pr[x] - g[x] /. {{x -> 100.`4342}, {x -> 100.`4343}};
% // N
Precision /@ %%
(*
  {0.00136186, -5.3138*10^-11}
  {26.7328, 4323.03}
*)
```

All I think of is that there is some internal catastrophic cancellation that goes undetected.  Note also that because of the need

Another possible issue, dwarfed by the precision one, is that the linear system constructed by the [Levin rule](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#32844337) is of dimension 48.  *Mathematica* balks at solving this system at high precision.  Perhaps with a significantly higher `"TimeConstraint"`, it might work.

The built-in [`"ExtrapolatingOscillatory"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#50593814) strategy seems a good candidate, but it turns out that it cannot parse the complicated integrand.  However we can imitate, as was done in [How to find a more precise value of integral?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125197/how-to-find-a-more-precise-value-of-integral/125204#125204)

Borrowing again from [Anton Antonov's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/49304/numerical-evaluation-of-a-sum/107360#107360), we can divide the interval of integration up at `x == Sqrt[2 Pi * i]` and represent it as a sum integrals between the nodes. I put a `Check[]` on the integral so I could investigate ones that did not converge.  We'll also be using the terms repeatedly, so it's good to memoize their values.

```
ClearAll[term];
mem : term[i_?NumberQ] := mem = Module[{iRes},
    Check[
     iRes = NIntegrate[(pr[x] - g[x]), {x, Sqrt[2 Pi*i], Sqrt[2 Pi*(i + 1)]},
       PrecisionGoal -> 20, AccuracyGoal -> 20, 
       WorkingPrecision -> 40 + 3 i, 
       Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 15}],
     Print["i = ", i]
     ];
    iRes];
```

To make it easy to code, I picked `x == Sqrt[2 Pi*i]`, `i = 16, 17, ...` for the nodes, but it leaves a little bit of the OP's integral from `x == 10` to `x == Sqrt[2 Pi*16]` to be added:

```
bit = NIntegrate[pr[x] - g[x], {x, 10, Sqrt[2 Pi*16]},
  PrecisionGoal -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 200]    
sf[n_] := Total@Table[SetPrecision[term[i], 200], {i, 16, n}]
```

We can then use Anton's `SearchSumValue[]` function (see below) to approximate the integral.

```
res = SearchSumValue[
  sf,                        (* partial sum function *)
  12,                        (* desired accuracy: abs. error < ~10^-12 *)
  30,                        (* number of terms to add each step *)
  40,                        (* starting number of terms *)
  Richardson[#1, #2, 24] &]  (* extrapolation function *)
answer = res[[2]] + bit      (* add the little bit to get the complete integral *)
(*
-7.4084729050246807289001990592571553616689002705033883146404497941764\
1713462740784131023302538755726602927879849993920908117244826729334375\
32927540835628437772008149977875*10^-6
*)
```

So the integral is estimated to be

```
-7.40847290*^-6
```

with an absolute error estimated by `SearchSumValue[]` to be at most `2.*^-15`.

*Further remarks (updated):*
The amplitude of `pr[x] - g[x]` appears to be about `(15 Sqrt[(π/2)] )/(32 x^5)`, which can be seen from `Simplify@Normal@Series[pr[x] - g[x], {x, Infinity, 5}]`.  I did a similar analysis as above with `pr[x] - g[x] + (15 Sqrt[(π/2)] )/(64 x^5)` with a different node grid and got the same result for the integral (subtracting the integral of `(15 Sqrt[(π/2)] )/(64 x^5)` from the sum, of course).  Here is a comparison with the "amplitude" `(15 Sqrt[(π/2)] )/(32 x^5)` (takes a while to run):

```
Plot[{RealExponent[g[x] - pr[x]], RealExponent[(15 Sqrt[(π/2)] )/(32 x^5)]},
 {x, 10, 100}, MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotRange -> All, WorkingPrecision -> 5000,
 PlotLegends -> {HoldForm@Log10@Abs[pr[x] - g[x]], HoldForm@Log10[(15 Sqrt[(π/2)] )/(32 x^5)]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

***Code dump:***

```
Clear[Richardson]
Richardson[A_, n_, N_] := 
 Total@Table[(A[n + k]*(n + k)^N*
      If[OddQ[k + N], -1, 1])/(k! (N - k)!), {k, 0, N}];

Clear[SearchSumValue]
SearchSumValue[partialSumFunc_, accGoal_, step_: 10, startStep_: 40, methodFunc_: Shanks] := 
  Block[{res, pf = 2}, 
   res = NestWhile[{#[[1]] + step, #[[3]], 
       methodFunc[partialSumFunc, #[[1]] + step]} &, {1, 
      methodFunc[partialSumFunc, startStep], 
      methodFunc[partialSumFunc, startStep + step]}, 
     Abs[N[#[[2]], pf*accGoal] - N[#[[3]], pf*accGoal]] > 10^-accGoal &];
   (*n-steps,estimate,error*)
   Append[res[[{1, 3}]], 
    Abs[N[res[[2]], pf*accGoal] - N[res[[3]], pf*accGoal]]]];
```