# What happened to SequenceLimit?

Tags: numerics, undocumented, compatibility, history

In older versions of *Mathematica*, there was a function called `SequenceLimit` that allowed taking the limit of a numerical sequence. It is useful for speeding up the convergence of numerical algorithms, and sometimes for getting them unstuck using the last few results. What happened to it? Any improvements available?

Comment: I mentioned this [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/834).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`SequenceLimit` became `` NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit ``. In the past, that change broke some of the examples on `NLimit` that used `SequenceLimit`. I reported the breakage, and the examples were fixed to use the same syntax but not actually call the now-non-existent function. The only remaining reference in the documentation that I can find to the use of `SequenceLimit` ***as if it were still a function*** is on the last bullet point of `NLimit`'s [detailed description](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/NumericalCalculus/ref/NLimit.html) for its `Method` option: "uses `SequenceLimit` on constructed sequence".

Recently, I started investigating the behavior of `` NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit `` because I need it in my engineering work. I feel `` NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit `` has some quite confusing shortcomings in regard to the approximation it returns vs. the number of terms supplied, so I wrote my own version below [from](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WynnsEpsilonMethod.html) [some](http://www.adamponting.com/wynns-epsilon-method/) [references](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a109445.pdf). I also posted a [C++ gist version on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/ChrisChiasson/c7c8e5827030e9f02c0b0b25b02dcc31).

A comparison appears below showing the convergence of partial sums of series approximations to `Pi` and `E`. Afterward, I use symbolic lists to document several parts of `` NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit `` that seem... possibly wrong... to me.

```
sPi@n_:=Sum[4(-1)^nn/(2nn+1),{nn,0,n}];
Table[sPi@n,{n,0,4-1}]//N
(*{4.,2.66667,3.46667,2.89524}*)

NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit@%
(*3.16667*)

sequenceLimit@%%
(*3.13333*)    
(*my answer is closer to Pi~=3.141, for good reason as shown
  below in the general case with 4 terms {a,b,c,d}*)

sE@n_:=Piecewise[{{(1+1/n)^n ,n!=0}},1] 
Table[sE@n,{n,0,4-1}]//N
(*{1.,2.,2.25,2.37037}*)

NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit@%
(*2.33333*)

sequenceLimit@%%
(*2.48214*)    
(*my answer is closer to E~=2.71828, for good reason as shown
  below in the general case with 4 terms {a,b,c,d}*)
```

Below, I illustrate the difference between the behavior of the built-in `` NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit `` function vs. my `sequenceLimit` function for symbolic lists, like `{a,b,c,d}`.

```
Quiet@NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit[{a,b,c}]
(*NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit[{a,b,c}]*)
(*yes, unevaluated with 3 inputs*)

sequenceLimit[{a,b,c}]//Simplify (*my function*)
(*(-b^2+a*c)/(a-2*b+c)*)
(*same as Mathematica's next result with 4 inputs*)

NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit[{a,b,c,d}]
(*(-b^2+a*c)/(a-2*b+c)*)
(*yes, only references a, b, & c not the later, more converged, d*)

sequenceLimit[{a,b,c,d}]//Simplify (*my function*)
(*(-c^2+b*d)/(b-2*c+d)*)
(*note use of d, which explains why my approximations
  for Pi and E above are better*)

NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit[{a,b,c,d,e}]
(*(-b^2+a*c)/(a-2*b+c)*) 
(*yes, same result as with 4 terms, no d or e in output*)

sequenceLimit[{a,b,c,d,e}]//Simplify (*my function*)
(*(c^3+a*d^2+b^2*e-c*(2*b*d+a*e))/
  (b^2+3*c^2-2*c*d+d^2-2*b*(c+d-e)-c*e-a*(c-2*d+e))*)
(*note use of d and e*)
```

I also document some error messages that seem spurious.

```
NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit[{a}]
(*NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit::seqw Sequence of length 1
  is too short for use with Degree -> 1*)
(*NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit::bdmtd WynnEpsilon is not
  a valid specification of a sequence limit extrapolation
  algorithm.*)
(*NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit[{a}]*)

NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit[{a},Degree->1]; (*Nulled output*)
(*NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit:optx Unknown option ° in 
  NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit[{a}]*)

NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit[{a},"Degree"->1]; (*Note quotes*)
(*NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit::optx Unknown option "Degree"
  in NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit[{a}]*)

sequenceLimit[{a}] (*sequence limit is my function*)
(*a*)

Quiet@NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit[{a,b}] (*Note Quiet & no evaluation*)
(*NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit[{a,b}]*)

sequenceLimit[{a,b}] (*my function*)
(*b*)
```

Everything above is from the current version of Mathematica Online.

```
$Version
(*11.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)*)
```

Here is the definition of my function

```
wynnE[-2,_,_]:=0
wynnE[-1,n_,s_]:=s@n
wynnE[rkp1_,n_,s_]:=(*wynnE[rkp1,n,s]=*)(*optional caching*)
 wynnE[rkp1-2,n+1,s]+1/(wynnE[rkp1-1,n+1,s]-wynnE[rkp1-1,n,s]) 

sequenceLimit[list_?VectorQ]:=
 With[{len=Length@list},
  With[{off=Boole@EvenQ@len},
   wynnE[len-2-off,off,list[[#+1]]&]
  ]/;len>0
 ]
```

Comment: DiscreteLimit[Sum[4 (-1)^nn/(2 nn + 1), {nn, 0, n}], n -> Infinity] performs \[Pi] .

Comment: Please give a concrete example.

Comment: I gave a compact implementation of Wynn $\varepsilon$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/36066). The generalization due to van den Broeck and Schwartz that I implemented [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96462) might be useful as well. Maybe you know this already, but you can use `PadeApproximant[]` as an additional check if you're using a sequence of partial sums of a power series.